# Error "GetAwaiter" accesible que acepte un primer argumento del tipo "List<Myobjeto>

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, asynctask

Estoy realizando un Rest API de consulta como lo expongo en este código:

```
 [HttpPost]
 protected async Task<IList<MyobjetoObject1>> ConsultaPuertos(int id, String 
 ubicacion, DateTime fecha)
 {
     PuertosGP puertosGPRepository = new PuertosGP();
   //ConsultaPuertos es una funcion que devuelve un list<>
   var resultList1 = puertosGPRepository.ConsultaPuertos(id, ubicacion, 
  fecha);
   return await resultList1;
  });
```

Me muestra el error antes mencionado en el título de este hilo
"GetAwaiter" ni se encuentra ningún método de extensión "GetAwaiter" accesible que acepte un primer argumento del tipo "List.

No se que me esta faltando.

Comment: ¿Cómo está definida la función `ConsultaPuertos` ? Lo más posible es que tu problema se deba a que esa función no es asíncrona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En principio debes devolver una lista obtenida de **modo asíncrono**, ya que tu Acción `ConsultaPuertos` devuelve un **Task Async**.

Puedes optar por devolver un resultado asíncrono con `ToListAsync()`, siempre que tu método `puertosGPRepository.ConsultaPuertos()` sea asíncrono:

```
var resultList1 = await puertosGPRepository.ConsultaPuertos(id, ubicacion, fecha).ToListAsync();
return resultList1;
```